# AS400 File Format Level Identifiers keep changing

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have this strange issue where I get a level check error when running a program. And I rectify the issue by recompiling the file and program. 
I use DSPFD to check the format level identifier for the file and DSPPGMREF to check the format level identifier for that file for the program and ensure that these match after re compiling and they do.

Then I used CALL to run the program and then I get a level check error. And when I used the same process to check the identifiers, the file's identifier has changed.

I have tried as much as I could think of, including deleting the file object completely and compiling and creating a new one, same for the program. 
I have also tried recompiling the file and programs with format level check attribute set to *NO 
Also WRKOBJ (*ALL/[filename]) on both file and program name showed only one object in the correct library. No other objects exist

Please help, this is very frustrating.

Screen shots below to show

BEFORE: 
[image: FILE Format Level Identifier Before]
[image: Program Format Level Identifier for File Before]
AFTER:
[image: FILE Format Level Identifier After]
[image: Program Format Level Identifier For File AFTER]

Comment: How many libraries does this file exist in? How many of them have different level identifiers? This smells like a library list problem to me.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say. I can't see what else it can possibly be.

Comment: I did wrkobj (*all/[filename]) for this file and program and they both only have one object that exist in only one library. Which I still deleted and then created new objects to replace them and same problem =/

Comment: How are you compiling it? Are you using a batch or interactive job, or are you using RDi? Could it be that the compile job is running under a user profile that has different authority than your user profile, and is thus able to see additional versions of the file?

Comment: The record format names are different.

Answer (score 3):

File record format level IDs don't change auto-magically...

Either the commenters are correct and you've got a library list issue and dealing with multiple copies...

Or something is being done to the file that changes the record format level ID.

Per the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/dm/rbal3detectdesc.htm)

> The system assigns a unique level identifier for each record format when it creates the associated file. The system uses the following information to determine the level identifier:
>
> - Record format name
> - Field name *(10 char system name, not long alias)*
> - Total length of the record format
> - Number of fields in the record format
> - Field attributes (for example, length and decimal positions)
> - Order of the field in the record format

You might try using Display File Field Description (DSPFFD) command before the compile and after the level check so you can determine what is changing.  Then it's a matter of tracking down where/why.